# ¿Cómo puedo migrar mi app a x64 bits en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Como bien ya deben saber Google Play decidió que a partir del 1 de agosto toda app debe ser compatible con dispositivos de 64 bits, por lo que si quieres actualizar o publicar una app, debe ser compatible.

He ahí mi problema: no encuentro la manera de habilitar las librerías a 64 bits. Al analizar mi app solo me muestra librerías `lib/armeabi-v7a` y `lib/x86`.

Ya intenté agregar a `build-gradle` la siguiente linea:

`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

Pero después de volver a analizar, aun me sigue mostrando estas librerías `lib/armeabi-v7a y lib/x86`.

Por favor agradecería que puedan ayudarme con este problema, ya que si no logro habilitar las librerías en 64 bits, no podré actualizarlas. Si necesitan más datos con gusto se los facilito.

De antemano muchas gracias.
[image: Este es el Build.gradle de la app]

[image: y este es el analisis de la apk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A partir del 1 de agosto de 2019, las apps que publiques en Google
>   Play tendrán que ser compatibles con arquitecturas de 64 bits. Las CPU
>   de 64 bits brindan a los usuarios experiencias más enriquecidas y
>   rápidas. Si agregas una versión de 64 bits a tu app, mejorarás su
>   rendimiento, favorecerás la innovación y podrás ofrecerla para
>   dispositivos que cuenten con hardware de 64 bits únicamente.

Puedes consultar el documento oficial:

**[Asegúrate de que tu app sea compatible con dispositivos de 64 bits](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)**

Generalmente no necesitas realizar mas que actualizar las bibliotecas y el SDK con el cual generas tu .APK.

> Si tu app usa únicamente código escrito en el lenguaje de programación
>   Java o Kotlin, incluidas las bibliotecas y SDK, es compatible con
>   dispositivos de 64 bits.

Pero es importante revisar si tu app hace uso de código nativo, ya que en este caso si necesitarás hacer uso de código nativo.

> Lo primero que debes hacer es verificar si tu app usa algún código
>   nativo. Los siguientes casos indican que sí lo hace:
>
> - Usa cualquier código (nativo) C/C++.
> - Se vincula con alguna biblioteca nativa de terceros.
> - Fue compilada por terceros que usan bibliotecas nativas.

En el caso que comentas, además de los directorios `lib/armeabi-v7a` y `lib/x86` que son para dispositivos de 32 bits, debes tener también las propias para 64 bits que son `lib/arm64-v8a` y `lib/x86_64`, para asegurar esto abre el .apk generado mediante `Build` > `Analyze APK`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no se tienen estos directorios genera tu .APK nuevamente pero asegura tener un   actualizado (minimo `targetSdkVersion 28`).

En el caso de usar el NDK También puedes habilitar la generación de builds para código nativo, definiendo de la arquitectura que deseas tu aplicación soporte:

```
 ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

En el caso de usar libraries de terceros, si tienes soporte es importante solicitar esta actualización para que tu app sea compatible, pero si la library es opensource o no tiene soporte tendrías que solicitarlo o realizar tu el cambio, lo cual pudiera ser problemático.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa: [Compila tu app con bibliotecas de 64 bits](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit?hl=es#building_with_android_studio_or_gradle)

Si cumples con lo anterior tendrás como resultado que sea compatible con el requerimiento de 64 bits

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ♦  agregue imagenes del build.gradle y del analisis de la apk si pudieses ayudarme por favor.